# How to acess files from an application in Android

Tags: android

I want to place one txt file (which have insert statements) of size 273 MB, i need to know how to save that file in Phone's memory and how to access that file from my application

If i able to access that file from my application i want to insert that data in my table,already i tried to use to save the file in my application's assets folder to acess the database using database helper but i heard that assets folder can store only files of size 1 MB but my database file size is 273 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `273mb size file`, I think better solution is just put the file in remote server, and using web request get data, also get the data only what you needed not all,

And put table structured database file (Without data) in `asset folder` and copy that file in application's `internal storage` then you have to download either file or data from server using web request and fill the database with it..

Update:

When you get data from server at server side make a `Select query using  OFFSET and LIMIT clause` so its returned only bounded limited rows and make request as intervaly so there is no work load on your server and in your application..

This is my personal opinion I may be wrong on this..

If any one has a better solution then please share it..

Thanks..

Comment: Actually earlier i used to get data from Web Request only but it's taking too much time to get data from server that's why i preferred this kind of approach

Comment: As per your data file is too large (273mb) You can't manage it with application's package..

Comment: Yaa, i agree that i can't manage in application's package but can i store the file in tablet's internal storage ? and  thencan i access it from there ? if yes can you please tell me how

Comment: First of all, if you can't handle large file in application's package then how can you put that file in tablet's internal storage? From where you copy that file?

Comment: Application's package in the sense i am saying in assets folder i can't manage it but i think once if i store it in internal storage we can access it from there and store it application database

Comment: And then whats the size of your application? I don't think any user will install too large application on their device?

Comment: This is a 3rd party application not for all users our client says there is no problem if the size is too large and right now the app size is 20 kb only but need to check after installing this 273 mb file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6598/discussion-between-kiran-b-and-user370305)

Comment: You can have large files (or a large number of smaller files) but will have to address: 1) how to transfer the data to the device (SD card? network download? USB transfer?) and 2) how to access efficently the data you need for each query (I presume you need each time just a small subset of the 273MB). BTW, possibly you can take advantage of compression, for the initial data load or possibly even during runtime.